# Iterate FormControl Errors in template

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to display all the errors on an Angular FormControl, but I can't loop through the errors object using an ngFor because it is not an array

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{property.label}}
        <div class="error-message">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let err of surveyForm.controls[property.label].errors">
                    {{ err}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-input [formControlName]="property.label">
    </ion-input>
 </ion-item>
```

*"Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays"*

How can I loop through an object like `errors`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `Pipe` which transforms your object in an array of object keys

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'objToKeys'
})
export class ObjToKeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (!value) {
      return value;
    }
    return Object.keys(value);
  }
}
```

And use this pipe like this:

```js
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{property.label}}
        <div class="error-message">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let key of surveyForm.controls[property.label].errors | objToKeys">
                    {{ surveyForm.controls[property.label].errors[key] }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-input [formControlName]="property.label">
    </ion-input>
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: I actually tried to implement this, but `surveyForm.controls[property.label].errors[key]` just resolves to the value `true`, not the actual error message